# Python generator using `yield` not producing the desired result

Tags: python-3.x, generator, yield

I am trying to find all the paths in a graph. I found this amazing function that I reproduce [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55767/finding-all-paths-from-a-given-graph):

```
def paths(graph, v):
    """Generate the maximal cycle-free paths in graph starting at v.
    graph must be a mapping from vertices to collections of
    neighbouring vertices.

    >>> g = {1: [2, 3], 2: [3, 4], 3: [1], 4: []}
    >>> sorted(paths(g, 1))
    [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3]]
    >>> sorted(paths(g, 3))
    [[3, 1, 2, 4]]

    """
    path = [v]                  # path traversed so far
    seen = {v}                  # set of vertices in path
    def search():
        dead_end = True
        for neighbour in graph[path[-1]]:
            if neighbour not in seen:
                dead_end = False
                seen.add(neighbour)
                path.append(neighbour)
                yield from search()
                path.pop()
                seen.remove(neighbour)
        if dead_end:
            yield list(path)
    yield from search()
```

However, as the information provided in the function indicates, this function yields paths that have completed, i.e. that hit a dead end. I would like to change the function to yield incomplete paths so `sorted(paths(g,1))` would return `[[1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3]]`.

I tried adding a this line `if not dead_end: yield list(path)` before the line that says `path.pop()`. But that ends up yielding some paths twice and won't yield the single node path. The result I got was `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 3]]` which is not what I want!

Is it possible to modify this code to yield "not completed" paths? Could you advice me how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! First, you'll need to yield your base case.

```
yield path
```

You'll need to do this before you even start iterating since getting to your first `yield` statement means you've already `append` ed something.

Second, your duplicates are coming from you second `yield` statement. Since you are now `yield` ing as you're iterating, you can remove that one completely.
Additionally, since we know `if neighbour not in seen:` then we haven't reached a dead end and therefore, `dead_end` is redundant and we can remove that.

So in summary:

```
def paths(graph, v):
    """Generate the maximal cycle-free paths in graph starting at v.
    graph must be a mapping from vertices to collections of
    neighbouring vertices.

    >>> g = {1: [2, 3], 2: [3, 4], 3: [1], 4: []}
    >>> sorted(paths(g, 1))
    [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3]]
    >>> sorted(paths(g, 3))
    [[3, 1, 2, 4]]

    """
    path = [v]                  # path traversed so far
    seen = {v}                 # set of vertices in path
    yield path

    def search():
        for neighbour in graph[path[-1]]:
            if neighbour not in seen:
                seen.add(neighbour)
                path.append(neighbour)
                yield from search()

                yield list(path)

                path.pop()
                seen.remove(neighbour)
    yield from search()

g = {1: [2, 3], 2: [3, 4], 3: [1], 4: []}

print(sorted(paths(g, 1)))
print(sorted(paths(g, 3)))
```

Also, `sorted()` could be traded out for `list()` since the first element will be identical for every yielded `list`.